# No sound on Ubuntu 18.04 (Spotify and YouTube don't work either)

Tags: sound, video, spotify

Since I updated Ubuntu from 16.x to 17.10 and then to 18.04 I don't have any sound. There is also a problem with videos in web browser (they look like a slideshow, still no sound) and Spotify, where it looks like music is loading but nothing happens.

[Alsa info script output](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=4d6e7ff287356a4cf5559d3bb95c153a2d1c0070)

Answer (score 2):

Probably this will solve your problem.

```
killall pulseaudio 
rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*
```

Comment: you really should explain what these commands do and how they are supposed to help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried re-installing pulseaudio and alsa? If not, type these commands in order.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio 
sudo apt install alsa-base pulseaudio 
sudo alsa force-reload
```

EDIT : For users with older versions of Ubuntu where `apt` is not there, use `apt-get`.

Comment: I did, but... what now?

Comment: Is pulseaudio is able to connect to the Audio Server?

Comment: Type `start-pulseaudio-x11` on Terminal to verify.

Comment: failed, unable to initialize

Comment: it fixed the issue on my computer

Comment: that does nothing to the "Spotify mutes on its own" issue. Also, removing alsa-base & pulse-audio remove some dependencies like 'ubuntu-desktop'. To clarify, the issue is that +/- randomly, spotify gets muted AND paused - this happens a lot when a terminal issues a bip (when typing a wrong key)

Comment: This advice completely destroyed my sound. It was not working in browsers before and after applying this suggestion my sound devices are disappeared from settings at all.

Update: started to working well after reboot.

Comment: Basic advice : Reboot before complaining. :)

Answer (score 0):

I came here from question

[Spotify mutes itself on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031947/spotify-mutes-itself-on-ubuntu-18-04)

which btw I don't think is duplicate of this but it is now closed as duplicate. So I write my answer here - the problem was actually caused by Teamspeak client that muted Spotify. When I turned of TS, Spotify didn't mute itself.

I found the way how to solve this issue here

https://forum.teamspeak.com/threads/138336-TeamSpeak-mutes-Spotify

You should check if

```
/etc/pulse/default.pa
```

contains following line

```
load-module module-role-cork
```

In case it does delete that line and restart Pulseaudio.