# No sound output from Spotify on 18.04

Tags: sound, 18.04, spotify

This is a similar problem to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033743/no-sound-on-ubuntu-18-04-spotify-and-youtube-dont-work-either) but I was unable to add to the comments since I am new to StackExchange. I tried the answer posted by Vishesh but it didn't solve the issue for me; when I run start-pulseaudio-x11 command it still says "Failure: Module initialization failed". However, the sound works for all my other applications (VLC, Rhythmbox, web-based audio such as YouTube and SoundCloud). I have not tried the solution posted by Vikas as I wasn't sure whether it would impact my applications that do have audio output.

The problem started when I switched my audio output to HDMI; I had plugged my computer into my TV.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

Comment: can you change the output in system settings -> sound -> applications?

Comment: It shows Spotify in the list under applications, sound is up full but still nothing from the app. I also tried to delete and reinstall the app with no success

Comment: An update to this issue: I still get full sound through an HDMI cable when its plugged into my TV. Does anyone know how to reset this in Spotify? All my other applications are working

Comment: The pavucontrol solution worked for me.... for no apparent reason spotify was muted. I just hit unmute and I started to hear the music. The funny thing is... I had closed spotify.... I can see it in the process list but the spotify app is not on my desktop...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The simplest solution is to install pavucontrol `sudo apt install pavucontrol`.
Then you launch it and the gui will let you choose the output for each application.

Comment: Easy to operate and worked greatly.

Comment: I am running Budgie and there are sound output controls easily accessible through the applet window however they weren't able to solve the problem. After I had unplugged the HDMI cable it was no longer listed as an output option and the check mark was beside Built-in Audio. Do you know if pavucontrol does a better job at controlling the sound devices?

Comment: Yes, that's the point (testing it could have been faster than type the comment).

Comment: this needs to be the recommended solution!

Comment: Thanks, I felt quite dumb plugging and unplugging my cables, mirroring my displays, etc. until I decided to read your answer.

Comment: Perfect solution. For some reason stop to sound my spotify. (No issues with the rest of the applications). With this app, I was able to enable the sound for spotify!

Comment: It worked with the PAV, the strange thing is that if I close the window, there is no audio after a few seconds (Spotify continues to play with no audio). If I open the PAV tool again, the audio is back. No big deal, I'm simply keeping that window open for now.

Comment: @ErikNorman I have encountered similar issues with other software, notably Zoom. It was happening because there was an option in Zoom to auto adjust the volume, which was overriding the levels I set in PAV. So I suggest going through and checking the settings within Spotify itself

Comment: It worked for me like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: perfect, was muted on spotify. solved! love u

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I experienced a similar problem today but not just with Spotify.

In my case, no application was able to play the sound.
Only system sounds were coming. 
 This occured after I had plugged my laptop to my TV using HDMI cable and then unplugged it.

This is how I solved it.

1. Connect your PC back to the Device using HDMI port
2. Go to display and mirror the screens
3. Go to settings>sound.
4. Change the audio output to the HDMI device
5. Change the audio output back to the laptop/PC
6. Go to display and switch back to your laptop screen
7. Unplug the HDMI cable

Comment: yes, flicking to digital spdif, then back to hdmi seems to solved it!

Comment: This also worked for me, thanks @coderDude! Strange that it was only Spotify affected for me..

Comment: worked on arch linux as well.  Thanks so much

Comment: This didn't worked for me. I recomend to choose the comment above as the acepted answer